# How to get a file using %APPDATA% in python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.9

I want to store in a variable this path `APPDATA%/Roaming/FileZilla/sitemanager.xml`.

When i use:

`file = "C:/Users/MyPC/AppData/Roaming/FileZilla/sitemanager.xml"`

it works, but when i use:

```
file = "%APPDATA%/Roaming/FileZilla/sitemanager.xml"
```

the file cannot be stored and i cant send via paramiko.

Anyone helps?

Comment: Python pathnames do not automatically know about environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the env variable with `getenv` function from `os` module. You can also use `Path` to easily manipulate paths.

```
import os
import pathlib

appdata = pathlib.Path(os.getenv('APPDATA'))
xmlfile = appdata / 'FileZilla' / 'sitemanager.xml'
```

Comment: it prints Roaming twice

Comment: i just removed 'Roaming' from your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.path.expandvars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars) to expand environment variables in a string. On Windows, $ and % forms are accepted.

```
import os
file = os.path.expandvars("%APPDATA%/Roaming/FileZilla/sitemanager.xml")
```

(Note the leading %)